# SQL (PostgreSQL): How to write a query to fetch the average salary of top 100 highest paid employees?

Tags: postgresql

What I have tried to solve this is:

```
SELECT AVG(amount) FROM (SELECT amount FROM payment ORDER BY amount LIMIT 100);
```

This also did not work.

```
SELECT AVG(highest_amount) FROM (SELECT amount AS highest_amount FROM 
payment ORDER BY amount LIMIT 100);
```

Sorry for asking silly questions. I am a newbie. :(

Comment: If you give your subquery an alias `FROM (…) AS t` and fix the ordering to `DESC`, it should work fine?

Comment: @Ryan Thank you! it does work! Well, I forgot DESC too. Thanks for correcting it too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the subquery in your first attempt an alias, it will work:

```
SELECT AVG(amount)
FROM
(
    SELECT amount
    FROM payment
    ORDER BY amount
    LIMIT 100
) t;
```

If you want an alternative method, which can be used without using `LIMIT`, then we can try using row number:

```
SELECT AVG(amount)
FROM
(
    SELECT amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY amount) rn
    FROM payment
) t
WHERE rn <= 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim! It works. Both of them. But you also forgot to sort the query in the descending order. Minor mistake. But thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this kind of problem is to use **WITH** queries, also know as Common Table Expression, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html the result is clear and easy to understand.

```
WITH top100 AS 
(
      SELECT 
             amount 
        FROM 
             payment
    ORDER BY 
             amount DESC
       LIMIT 
             100
)
SELECT 
       avg(amout) 
  FROM 
       top100;
```

Comment: The problem is resolved for me, but learning the alternate ways is also great. So, thanks a lot for your response Rodolphe! :)

Comment: My pleasure Annu, I did it in this spirit :)